# How to print 2 newlines in java?

Tags: java, newline, blank-line

I know that

```
for

example
```

is printed by: `System.out.print("for" + "\n" + "example")`
But what do I do when I want to print 2 blank lines instead of 1?
Like this:

```
for


example
```

I tried `System.out.print("for" + "\n" + "\n" + "example")` but it still printed 1 blank line

Answer (score 11):

`System.out.print("for" + "\n\n\n" + "example")` should solve your problem. The first `"\n"` is for ending `"for"` and then two blank lines

or

```
System.out.println("for");
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("example");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of printing two newlines:

1. Write an empty print statement twice or more:

   ```
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println();
   ```
2. `System.out.print( "\n\n\n" )`
3. Use a loop in case you want to use a single `println` and even without using `/n`:

   ```
   public void foo(int n) {
       if (n > 3) 
           return;
       println(currNum);
       foo(n+1);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
System.out.println("for");
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("example");
```

To print what you need.

```
System.out.println();
```

just prints an empty line.

As for your solution, you actually need **3** new line characters (one after "for" and two empty lines).

Your first statement is wrong, as:

```
System.out.print("for" + "\n" + "example")
```

will print:

```
for 
example
```

Comment: Oooh I didn't know about this. I'm so noob lol. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` should return the operator you are looking for. My guess is that this property depends from OS'es. You can use this to print two separate lines:

```
System.out.prinln("line 1"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"line 2");
```

This will print:

```
line 1
line 2
```